# Webpack + React + TypeScript: Module not found ... in ... node_modules/react/

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to put together a very basic project with React, TypeScript and Webpack.  When I compile I get the following errors from the `react` folder in `node_modules` (I've removed the stack traces and my project's path for brevity):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/emptyFunction' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/emptyFunction' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/emptyObject' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/emptyObject' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/invariant' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fbjs/lib/warning' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'object-assign' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'object-assign' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'prop-types/checkPropTypes' in '.../node_modules/react/cjs'
```

I tried uninstalling TypeScript and replacing it with Babel to transpile the JSX and got the same error.  **Installing `babel-preset-2015` fixed it**.

I've tried just about every combination of `target` and `module` in `tsconfig.json` to get the same result in TypeScript but couldn't get anything working.  **How can I get Webpack, TypeScript, and React working together?**

I've worked with all three of these technologies before, is it a recent compatibility problem?  If so what are the most recent compatible versions?

I've seen a few other questions similar to this one where the solution was installing `fbjs` directly in the project - I've tried this too without success.

## Files

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "es2015"
  },
  "exclude": ["build"]
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        dev: "./src/index.tsx",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./build/index.js",
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Typescript
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
        ],
    },
};
```

### package.json

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^16.0.28",
        "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
        "typescript": "^2.6.2",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.2.0"
    }
}
```

### ./src/index.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

const a = <div />;
```

(I'm running this with Node 9.2.1 and NPM 5.6.0 installed)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Webpack is not resolving `.js` files. Add this to your `webpack.config.js`.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
},
```

Here is the `tsconfig.json` I used to run your example.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That did it!  For anyone who comes by here with the same problem, the minimal `tsconfig` works too, still thanks for giving your complete setup!

Answer (score -6):

In VSCode, check Deno Extension and set it Enable(Workspace)