# Webpack - Update React 18 — Module not found 'ReactDOM/client'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've proposed upgrading —lucky of me— the React version of our project from v17.0.2 to v18.x.

While the `npm i` is done fine, I have the problem that when I want to import the `createRoot` method from `react-dom/client` I get the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom/client' in 'My-local-path'

If I don't import this module, the app correctly compiles, however, if I do, even if I don't use `createRoot`, I get the error.

**appLoader.js** (index.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'; // this breaks the app

// this works fine
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Route component={() => 'hello world'} />
    </MemoryRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// const container = document.getElementById('root');
// if (container) {
//   createRoot(container).render(
//     <React.StrictMode>
//       <MemoryRouter>
//         <Route component={() => 'hello world'} />
//       </MemoryRouter>
//     </React.StrictMode>
//   );
// }
```

I suspect that this has to do with Webpack. I saw [here](https://devrr.com/cannot-find-module-react-dom-client-from-pure-js/) that it might be related of not including the module in Webpack.

We don't use Jest, therefore [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713405/cannot-find-module-react-dom-client-from-node-modules-testing-library-react) won't apply.

1. Also tried adding `externals` to webpack like commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168446/module-not-found-cant-resolve-reactdom)
2. I've tried deleting `package-log.json` then removing `node_modules` and reinstalling.
3. Played with several options in babel.config.js
4. Wrapping all the components with `React.StrictMode`

My **webpack.config.js**

```
require('env2')('./.env');

const _ = require('lodash');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require('moment-locales-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackAssetsManifest = require('webpack-assets-manifest');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const ifDev = (then) => (isDev ? then : null);
const ifProd = (then) => (!isDev ? then : null);

module.exports = {
  target: isDev ? 'web' : ['web', 'es5'],
  profile: true,
  mode: isDev ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: {
    sso: [
      './sso/publicPath',
      ifDev('webpack-hot-middleware/client?dynamicPublicPath=true'),
      ifDev('react-hot-loader/patch'),
      './sso/appLoader',
    ].filter(_.identity),
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: isDev,
    minimize: !isDev,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        // fix bug "cannot declare const twice..." in Safari 10
        minify: TerserPlugin.uglifyJsMinify,
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: { safari10: true },
          toplevel: true,
          output: { comments: false },
        },
        extractComments: false,
      }),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  performance: { hints: false },
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
  devtool: false,
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: isDev ? '[name].bundle.js' : '[name].bundle.[contenthash].js',
  },
  // tried this
  // externals: {
  //   'react': { commonjs: 'react', commonjs2: 'react', amd: 'react', root: 'React' },
  //   'react-dom': { commonjs: 'react-dom', commonjs2: 'react-dom', amd: 'react-dom', root: 'ReactDOM' },
  // },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
      stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    },
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, './assets'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), // include your file like this in less files: ~@/yourFile.less
      '../../theme.config$': path.join(
        __dirname,
        './src/theme/semantic/theme.config.less'
      ), // semantic requirement
      'react-dom': isDev ? '@hot-loader/react-dom' : 'react-dom',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ process: 'process/browser' }),
    ifDev(
      new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: '[file].map',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      })
    ),
    ifProd(
      new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [
          '**/*',
          path.join(process.cwd(), 'logs/**/*'),
        ],
        verbose: true,
      })
    ),
    ifProd(new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ minimize: true, debug: false })),
    new MomentLocalesPlugin(),
    ifDev(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()),
    new WebpackAssetsManifest({
      publicPath: true,
      writeToDisk: true,
      entrypoints: true,
      output: '../rendering-manifest.json',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].bundle.[contenthash].css',
    }),
    ifProd(
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [{ from: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/static') }],
      })
    ),
  ].filter(_.identity),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
          ifProd(path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/joi')),
        ].filter(_.identity),
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|less)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: { importLoaders: 1, sourceMap: isDev },
          },
          { loader: 'less-loader', options: { sourceMap: isDev } },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.ico$|\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.svg$|\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              esModule: false,
              name: isDev ? '[name].[ext]' : '[name].[contentHash].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My **babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  sourceType: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'unambiguous' : 'module',
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-react', { 'runtime': 'automatic' }],
    ['@babel/preset-env', {
      loose: true,
      useBuiltIns: 'usage',
      corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true },
      modules: false,
      targets: { browsers: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'chrome 53, safari 10, >0.1%' : 'chrome 86, safari 10' },
    }],
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
  ],
};
```

My partial **package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.5",
    "downscale": "^1.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.4",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "file-dialog": "0.0.8",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "less": "^3.12.2",
    "less-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.4.8",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "react-rangeslider": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.22.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "search-parser": "^0.1.19",
    "semantic-ui-less": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "tachyons": "^4.12.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.9.0",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.3.0",
    "@supercharge/promise-pool": "^1.6.0",
    "applicationinsights": "^1.8.10",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "env2": "^2.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.17.5",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "joi": "^17.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.4",
    "knex": "^0.21.12",
    "locutus": "^2.0.14",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mjml": "^4.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "mssql": "^6.2.3",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.20",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
    "npm": "^8.13.2",
    "parse": "^2.17.0",
    "parse-dashboard": "^2.1.0",
    "parse-server": "^4.4.0",
    "query-string": "^6.13.7",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.11.0",
    "redis": "^4.2.0",
    "saslprep": "^1.0.3",
    "sharp": "^0.26.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  }
```

Comment: Show dependencies sections as well. Especially react and react dom

Comment: Oh right, that's weird this project has react and react-dom in the dev deps. I'll update with the list.

Comment: Same results with react and react-dom in deps instead dev btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that this project is use the dependency `@hot-loader/react-dom`, and it was overriding `react-dom`.

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), // include your file like this in less files: ~@/yourFile.less
      '../../theme.config$': path.join(
        __dirname,
        './src/theme/semantic/theme.config.less'
      ), // semantic requirement
      // 'react-dom': isDev ? '@hot-loader/react-dom' : 'react-dom', // this was overriding the react-dom version in node_modules
    },
  },
};
```

By the way, the aforementhioned dependency has been deprecated, so if you want to upgrade React you'll have to find an alternative like [react-refresh-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin)